# How to use GC.KeepAlive() and for what purpose?

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection

How can we use [`GC.KeepAlive()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.gc.keepalive) and what is the purpose?

I transfer files from terminal (Windows-CE) to Server using Socket. The time needed for transfer is 8 minutes. After 5 minutes the Windows-CE shuts down (if touch screen not pressed)

If I use `GC.KeepAlive()` for this, does this solve my problem?

Comment: Did you tried using that API? As per MSDN, it seems true or might work since WinCE are on unmanaged code

Answer (score 22):

You very rarely need to use `GC.KeepAlive` - *very* rarely. You'd use it if you wanted to prevent the side-effect of a finalizer from occurring too early, for example. I've most often seen it used for [`Mutex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex.aspx) - keeping mutex alive until the end of an app to make sure there's only one instance. (A `using` statement is actually better here, but that's a separate matter.)

And no, it doesn't sound like it's relevant in your situation.

Comment: As per MSDN, wince are on unmanaged objects. So to make it persistence what msdn says is true here right?

Comment: @zenwalker: CE supports managed and native code both, though neither is relevant to the problem at hand.

Comment: What about COM objects?

Comment: @codea: What about them? It sounds like you have a very specific example in mind, but I can't tell what it is. (For me, COM objects would count as "very rarely" anyway, to be honest...)

Comment: @JonSkeet effectively, something very specific (an SDK based on COM).  And from what I understood so far, the thing that counts the most is to hold  a reference to your most important COM objects to make sure they dont' get garbage collected... I will open a new question in case I need to go further in that direction.  Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

From the MSDN library for .NET:

> The purpose of the KeepAlive method is to ensure the existence of a
>   reference to an object that is at risk of being prematurely reclaimed
>   by the garbage collector. A common scenario where this might happen is
>   when there are no references to the object in managed code or data,
>   but the object is still in use in unmanaged code such as Win32 APIs,
>   unmanaged DLLs, or methods using COM.

So not this would not solve your problem. In fact it's not even related to your problem.
The only thing you can do is in the service/application running on the Windows CE, adding code that prevents the system to shutdown as long as the transfer is in progress

Comment: Is wince stuffs are unmanaged objects? So as per MSDN, it holds true right?

Comment: Just because you're running on Windows CE doesn't mean it's unmanaged, as there's an entire .NET platform available for CE specific devices

Comment: May be if its assumed that wince on unamanged. Then keepalive wud be helpful?

Comment: GC.KeepAlive is for garbage collection on unreferenced objects, it has nothing to do with your socket connection.

Answer (score 3):

The screen powering down is a power-management setting on the device.  It's going to happen whether or not any app is running.  The GC has absolutely nothing to do with this.

If you want to prevent the power maanger from putting hte device into a low-power state, you have a few options.  You can periodically call [SystemIdleTimerReset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa930260.aspx) in your app.

You could force the power state to something you like with [SetSystemPowerState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms920754.aspx).

You could change the power manager timeouts to something more to your liking by adjusting settings at `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power\Timeouts]` (followed by a WM_SETTINGS_CHANGE broadcast IIRC).

The best "solution" is going to depend on your app requirements, your users' requirements and the power management system of the target device.